# Executing command doesn't result in script exception

Tags: powershell, error-handling, sqlcmd

We have a powershell script that deploys a database script. However, if the database script fails, the output doesn't throw exceptions to the powershell script.

Below is an example of the .ps1 file:

```
function Publish-DatabaseProject 
{
    sqlcmd -S . -b -v DatabaseName=Integration -q "alter table xx add test Varchar(10)"
}

function Add-Timestamp {
    process {
        if ($_.GetType() -eq [string]) {
            "[$(Get-Date -Format o)] $_"
        } else {
            $_
        }
    }
}

function Write-LogFile {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $Path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)] [object[]] $InputObject
    )

    begin {
        $root = Split-Path -Path $Path -Parent
        if ($root -and !(Test-Path -Path $root)) { New-Item -Path $root -Type Directory 
                              | Out-Null }
    }

    process {
        $InputObject |
            Add-Timestamp |
            Tee-Object -File $Path -Append
    }
}

Publish-DatabaseProject -ErrorVariable DeployError 2>&1 |
    Write-LogFile -Path "C:\output.log"

if ($DeployError -and $DeployError.Count -ne 0) 
{
    Write-Output "Failed"
} else 
{
    Write-Output "Succeeded"
}
```

The query in question is executing against a non-existent table. The text output shows:

> [2015-12-11T14:42:45.1973944+00:00] Msg 4902, Level 16, State 1, Server ABDN-DEV-PC1, Line 1
>
> [2015-12-11T14:42:45.2053944+00:00] Cannot find the object "xx" because it does not exist or you do not have permission
>   s.
>
> Succeeded

I am expecting the last line to read: Failed.

If you run the sqlcmd line on its own, and follow it up with `$LastExitCode`, it does spit out a non-zero exit code.

```
> sqlcmd -S . -b -v DatabaseName=Integration -q "alter table xx add test Varchar(10)"
Msg 4902, Level 16, State 1, Server ABDN-DEV-PC1, Line 1
Cannot find the object "xx" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
> $LastExitCode
1
```

For various reasons, we cannot use `Invoke-SqlCmd`, and need to stick with SQLCMD.exe.

How can we make exceptions from within SQLCMD bubble out correctly to the calling script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `-ErrorVariable DeployError` statement would only get triggered if the `Publish-DatabaseProject` cmdlet itself fails to execute.  As that function is mostly a wrapper around sqlcmd.exe, there isn't any intelligence to bubble up this error.  We can wrap it though by using the `$LastExitCode` automatic variable.

```
function Publish-DatabaseProject 
{
    sqlcmd -S . -b -v DatabaseName=Integration -q "alter table xx add test Varchar(10)"
    if ($LastExitCode -ne 0)
       {
    Write-error $LastExitCode

    throw $LastExitCode
      }
}
```

Now, PowerShell will catch this error from the .exe, and you can use `-ErrorVariable`.

**Update**

So, since you want to keep running and not abandon ship when enountering an error, we need to wrap your `Publish-DataBaseProject` function with a `try{}catch{}` block, to catch the error we're generating, without stopping execution.

```
try {Publish-DatabaseProject -ErrorAction STOP -ErrorVariable DeployError 2>&1 |
    Write-LogFile -Path "C:\output.log" }


 catch{
      Write-Output "Current job $($_), failed"
      Write-Output "Exception $($Error.ExceptionID)"
      }
```

Now we're properly generating an exception from a CMD, bubbling it up through our Function, and handling it as if it were a normal function, all using Native PowerShell.  I believe this is what you were seeking to do.  If not, post a gist of the whole script and I'll help you in a more targeted fashion.

Comment: It is a minor niggle, but Publish-DatabaseProject is a function not a cmdlet.

Comment: You're right, I use the terms interchangeably because I'm bad at my job.

Comment: It is a common thing and it wasn't meant to demean your answer. Just pointing it out for anyone that didn't understand that there is a difference.

Comment: @EBGreen - It's actually a cmdlet in the code, now I think about it, the above is just my boiled down code whilst trying to find the issue.

Comment: @FoxDeploy - This answers my question. However,  in some of the code, we actually call `sqlcmd` as part of a `foreach-object` loop. In those cases, we'd want to continue with the additional db calls, but have the end result as "Failed". Could this still be done with your example?

Comment: I would move the `if($deployError and $deployerror.count)` statement into your forEach.  Then you would have error reporting for each step of the process.

Comment: @FoxDeploy In reality - when it fails, it actually sends an email - we'd only want that once for the entire run.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Throw is a terminating error type, lemme revisit this to set you up the right way with a soft error instead.